# html5 datepicker onchange open another datepicker

Tags: html, jquery

I am using the html5 datepicker:

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker" />
```

Now I would like to open the datepicker widget of datepicker2

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker2" />
```

If #datepicker fired an onchange event.
The onchange event works, but how can I open the datepicker widget of #datepicker2 with jquery?

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6909

Answer (score 0):

To open the datepicker you need to trigger click on calendar icon which is

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

And you can't do that by JavaScript or Jquery so you can use JQueryUI which has a datepicker component and you can show it by just saying:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("show");
```